# Como puedo modificar la compresión de Docker GZIP (servidor web)

Tags: web, docker, web.config

mi servidor web es muy lento y despues de utilizar la herramienta `PageSpeed` de google Crhome, me ha recomendado que habilite la compresion.

Estoy utilizando Docker, y mi proyecto esta dentro de un contenedor y lo levando mediante la maquina virtual por defecto.

El problema es que no se como decirle a la configuración de Docker que me comprima por GZIP.

¿Sabéis como puedo modificar su configuración para cambiar el método de compresión? (o activarlo). ¿Hay otra forma de poder comprimir mi proyecto a la hora de lanzarlo?

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando algún webserver dentro del contenedor como Apache o nginx?

Comment: @ElAsiduo Apache

Comment: Has intentado cambiar la configuración del webser, Apache en este caso, por ejemplo como se explica [aquí](https://blog.intropedro.com/es/content/activar-la-compresi%C3%B3n-gzip-en-apache-httpd)?